# Every cyclic group is abelian, so does that mean that "if cyclic then abelian" ??

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to simplify the statement that "every cyclic group is abelian" by using an "if-then" statement.

However, i am not sure whether the right statement is "if cyclic then abelian" or "if abelian then cyclic"...

Your help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Whenever I sleep I breathe, yet it is not true that whenever I breathe I sleep.  - the Dormouse

Comment: The question you are being asked is stupid. The statement "every cyclic group is Abelian" is as simple as it can be. The precise formal statement will depend on the precise system you're working in. It can be used pretty much as-is within NBG theory, for example, since the cyclic groups form a class, while in ZF it would have to be converted to the schema "If $G$ is a cyclic group then $G$ is Abelian." Inherently, though, the statement is perfectly simple and clear.

Answer (score 1):

The correct statement is "if a group $G$ is cyclic, then it is abelian" - meaning any cyclic group is abelian. If you're not convinced, try to think of an abelian group that is not cyclic (**Hint:** look at groups of order $4$). Once you find one abelian group that isn't cyclic, you can see that the statement "if a group is abelian, then it is cyclic" is false.

Answer (score 0):

"Every cyclic group is abelian" means "For all groups G, if G is cyclic, then G is abelian." If-then statements are often stated without the "For all", but it's still implied: "If G is a cyclic group, then G is abelian."